# Can I show only different dates on labels in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, highcharts

[image]

Is it possible to reduce the congestion of labels in highchart as shown in screenshot?

Comment: what is it supposed to do with angular?

Comment: And to answer your question yes you can show only 1 date for same date entries. You can group them together and take one value out. Now how you want to group them is up to you. Taking an average would be one possible solution

Comment: thanks for the reply.. how can i grouped them??

Comment: Group as is you can select all the items that belong to same date and then take average of that, or take max value or take min value and use that to plot the graph. And you can show the the detailed entries in the tooltip. how to show them in tooltip you can find in the docs of highcharts

Comment: You can show exactly how few, or how many labels you want per day. Use [`tickInterval`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval) to specify the *tick interval*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle where you can change the `tickInterval` to update the chart: http://jsfiddle.net/ucL63dye/28/

```js
var timearray = [];
var time = new Date().valueOf();
var delay = 50 * 60 * 1000; //50 minutes
for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
  timearray[i] = new Date(i * delay + time).toLocaleString('en-us', {day: 'numeric', month: 'short', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: false});;
}
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        tickInterval: 3,
        categories: timearray
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
#tick {
  width: 50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```